# Activate Intel VT-d in the kernel on CentOS7

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, centos7, virsh, intel-vt-x

Following many tutorials, they ask you to alter the grup file at the 
/boot/grup/grup.conf.. but in Centos7 there is no /boot/grup/grup.conf

...

Activate Intel VT-d in the kernel
Activate Intel VT-d in the kernel by appending the intel_iommu=on parameter to the kernel line of the kernel line in the /boot/grub/grub.conf file.
The example below is a modified grub.conf file with Intel VT-d activated.

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora Server (2.6.18-190.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-190.el5 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-190.el5.img
```

?? how to activate the inter vt-d

Answer (score 5):

In CentOS 7, append the kernel command line parameters to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` entry in `/etc/sysconfig/grub`.

For example, change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rd.lvm.lv=centos/root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  vconsole.keymap=us rhgb quiet"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rd.lvm.lv=centos/root vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  vconsole.keymap=us rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on"
```

Then regenerate the grub configuration with `dracut`:

```
dracut --regenerate-all --force
```

Comment: How can I verify that the PCI is Activated in the Kernal